# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp12\htdocs\Website\dbconnect2.php on line 26

Tags: php, mysqli

My code is not working. Error is:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp12\htdocs\Website\dbconnect2.php on line 26

This my code:

```
<?php class DBController {
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "Admin";
private $password = "1234";
private $database = "dbtest";

function __construct() {
    $conn = $this->connectDB();
    if(!empty($conn)) {
        $this->selectDB($conn);
    }
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
    return $conn;
}

function selectDB($conn) {
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $this->database);
}

function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connectDB(),$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}

function numRows($query) {
    $result  = mysqli_query($query);
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;       } } ?>
```

Comment: Read the documentation and you know what is wrong: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

In the runQuery function, you are using mysqli_query in wrong way.
Correct way is

```
 mysqli_query($this->connectDB(),$query);
```

where $conn is the mysql object which is build with mysqli_connect function.

Comment: **It show this error now.**                                    ** Notice: Undefined variable:** conn in C:\xampp12\htdocs\Website\dbconnect2.php on line 25

**Warning:** mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp12\htdocs\Website\dbconnect2.php on line 25

**(Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp12\htdocs\Website\dbconnect2.php on line 26)**

Comment: @MubasherSalam Don't just copy paste the code. Look for the connection variable build with mysqli_connect and replace that variable with $conn

Comment: I use your correct way but it shows up one errors. I fix all errors just that 2 left that why I posted. can you fix that and send me again.

Comment: @MubasherSalam I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks it works now but only one more error left can you help me on that. can you check below mysqli_query because that have some boolean error

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp12\htdocs\Website\dbconnect2.php on line 26

Comment: Mark it accepted if it works for you

Your query is wrong. Show error with this,     $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error($this->connectDB()));

Comment: You can mark accepted answer like this. http://i.prntscr.com/724f532f73574282b5335bda587e429f.png
just click that to accept so other users can take advantage from it.

Comment: still have problem

Comment: Yes obviously, the code i shared will let you know the exact error. Follow that error and correct the query.

Comment: still showing that boolean error

Comment: Replace this code $result = mysqli_query($query); with $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error($this->connectDB())); everywhere.

Comment: now this showing mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in